# How to create charts like below using highcharts in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

[image]

how to create bar charts like this one in highcharts. I have tried barcharts to acheive this but not helped. help me out in this.

Comment: hey ! you should provide some code in order to help you. This example  https://jsfiddle.net/vnhjcqow/ I found in the doc is exactly what you want is it ? As you can see you can use column with range.

Comment: based on your answer i have created the chart like this https://jsfiddle.net/venkatesh_karthick/d2ej4rz3/. thank you for that but whenever i try to replicate the same in my angular project it is showing error like. highcharts error 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `columnrange` series type, which is a part of `highcharts-more` module (remember to import and initialize it in Angular project).

```
series: [{
    type: 'columnrange',
    data: [...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x3r09d2f/

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/master/README.md

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange